# When I am voting on a question, my vote disappears if I click on the question title immediately afterwards

Tags: discussion, bug, up-votes

I have been experiencing something rather kinda odd, when I vote on a question, then immediately afterwords I click the question title, it reloads the page, and my vote hasn't been registered.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: It's an AJAX system.  If you reload the page before the voting AJAX transmits, your vote won't get registered.

Comment: How long should I wait? and what if I vote and immediately go back to the SO home page, how many votes aren't casted because of that?

Comment: For what purpose are you refreshing the page?  Most of the important notifications will get AJAX'ed back to you, so a refresh (especially an immediate one) should not be required.

Comment: That said, a few seconds should suffice. Slow connections (like VPN's) can have an impact on how long a vote takes to register.

Answer (score 6):

AJAX is asynchronous and uses "callback" code to indicate that it is done.

If you reload the page before the message is done on the server, then your vote might not be counted.

Depending on your interweb speeds this could be anywhere from 1MS to 10 seconds (give or take).

---

To sum it all up:

### jQuery

Comment: Vote Down requires 125 reputation